# How to convert HTML content which has SVG and JS file inside into Image without using Webbrowser UI Control in C#?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, svg

I have one webpage which has html + svg + Javascript file. actually this is a designed layout file such as card designing image at the web application side.

now i need to printout this designed image in my PC from the webapp.

So i start to write one service app which will monitor this PRINT request and start reading the image content from DB.

Now . I can convert the HTML + SVG file into image using SVG library successfully.  BUT Now that image has JS file also which is some barcode content.

So now i need to convert full page into Image in C# application without using WEBCONTROL since i am developing C# Service application.

sample html code which need to convert into Image

```
<html> <head> <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=9' /> 


<script src="JsBarcode.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="BarcodeGen.js"></script>
<script>UpdateBarcodePrint();</script> 

</head> <svg width="1012" height="638" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
 <!-- Created with smartbadge -->

 <g>
  <title>background</title>
  <rect x="-1" y="-1" width="1014" height="640" id="canvas_background" fill="#fff"/>
 </g>
 <g>
  <title>Barcode3</title>
  <image stroke="null" xlink:href="C:/Users/saddam.h/Pictures/art.jpg" id="svg_1_1477469772076" height="631.33335" width="1006.00004" y="6" x="5"/>
  <image db-barcode_Values="1" db-barcode="Col_ID" x="290.66667" y="61" class="barcode" width="330.66669" height="100" id="svg_2_1477394920232" xlink:href="1"/>
 </g>
</svg></html>
```

How do i achieve this . pls help.